# avoid both screen lock and pattern lock

Tags: screen, lock-screens

When the screen times out, a screen lock activates that needs to be swiped down. After 5 minutes, a phone lock pattern is activated. Now when I turn on the display I need to both swipe down and enter the unlock pattern.

Is there an option to not need to do both? Optimally, I want the first 5 minutes to require a swipe down and after 5 minutes to require the pattern

I'm using htc desire hd, android 2.2, unrooted (is there a fix when rooted?)

Answer (score 1):

Under Settings -> Location and security there is an option for "Lock screen after" where you can choose how long before the pattern is required.  With this setting changed you can turn the phone off and back on and only have to swipe down.

Under Settings -> Display there is an option for "Screen timeout" that should change the amount of time before the phone goes to sleep.

As far as I know the swipe down is not optional.

Comment: In 2.3.2, when using lock pattern, I do not find any setting for a "lock screen after" timeout... :-(