# Only use pattern lock instead of swipe screen and pattern lock

Tags: lock-screens

On my first Android phone, the Droid (running stock Android OS), when the pattern lock was enabled, that would be the only lock screen I was presented with when turning on the screen.

Now I'm using a Droid 3 and it has a "2-stage" lock screen when the pattern lock is enabled. So when I turn on the screen, I have to first swipe to unlock and then enter the pattern after that. Is there any way to go back to the original Droid experience of a single lock screen, even with the pattern lock enabled?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/avoid-both-screen-lock-and-pattern-lock.  Does that help?

Comment: That questions deals more with timing of the pattern lock screen after the swipe screen. I want to disable to swipe screen so only the pattern lock screen is necessary.

Comment: My bad, I pasted that without fully re-reading it.  I though there was another question the same as yours but I can't find it.  Anyways, hopefully someone knows how to do this.

Comment: That sounds like some bug to me in motoBLUR (or what ever they call it now). I am running android 2.3.5 and when I enable pattern lock, it is the only screen that I see when turning the device back on.

Comment: Ryan, I agree it is something that is part of Motorola's skin, because as I mentioned, it was not an issue when I was running stock Android. Hoping a Motorola Android expert could help.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, a common gripe in several of the  custom manufacturer UIs. HTC Sense also makes you perform two unlock actions, and since the UI's lockscreen is so entwined with the framework it is apparently very difficult to remove (I don't know of any way to do it on either Motoblur or Sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without rooting, etc there is no way on the Droid 3 to go back to the Droid 1 lockscreen experience. Motorola and their forum users recommend using a lock timer so you don't have to use the pattern every time.

[Motorola Forum Post](https://supportforums.motorola.com/message/442106)