# Is there a lock-screen that can unlock without swiping across screen

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-droid-incredible, htc-sense, lock-screens

My father has an HTC Incredible, and a major source of frustration is that the Sense lock-screen uses a swipe gesture to unlock, which for some reason is very difficult for him, especially when trying to answer a call.

I can turn the lock-screen off, but this results in the answer and decline call buttons being active immediately, which could result in premature answering, or accidental hang-ups.

I've also looked into some of the security options, as replacing the swipe gesture wholly with a short PIN or password (skip the gesture, only enter the PIN) would likely solve this problem. Losing the ability to answer from he lock-screen is acceptable. Unfortunately, these options still require the gesture to get to them on Sense (and on my own phone running CyanogenMod, as well).

The hardware is out of warranty, so I can root and flash CyanogenMod if I need to lose HTC Sense to do something.

Comment: Similar to [this question for the Droid 3](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12106/only-use-pattern-lock-instead-of-swipe-screen-and-pattern-lock).  You might be in the same boat, with no recourse, though it's quite surprising that CM doesn't give you the option.

Comment: Indeed similar. I saw that question as I was researching this, which is why I am open to whole-sale replacement of the lock-screen app. Just that every lock-screen I've found has some sort of dragging gesture to unlock.

Comment: CM does give you the option - see my answer. I was under the assumption that OP was running stock on this phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it amounts to recommending major surgery for a small problem, CyanogenMod has customizable lock-screen controls. (My wife's G1 is configured to unlock when she pushes the menu button.)

Of course this requires rooting, modding, and hardware buttons...but it's a solution.

Comment: Don't I feel sheepish. Didn't even think to look in CyanogenMod settings. I mean, the top lockscreen option disables the lockscreen if a security lock is active. Staring me in the face, it was. :/

Answer (score 0):

Is it any swiping motion that is difficult, or just the default left to right swipe?  If a small swipe in a different direction would work, you could try [Ripple Lock](http://solateam.blogspot.com/2011/06/ripple-lock.html).  This lock screen replacement requires that you drag an inner circle to the edge of an out circle.  The direction is not important, and the swipe distance is about half of the regular lock screen.

Comment: As far as I can tell (I never had a problem with it myself), it was the swiping gesture itself that was the problem.