# Draw unlock pattern without having to swipe first

Tags: lock-screens, android-10, pattern-lock

When an **Android 10** phone is locked, it shows notifications and says "Swipe to unlock", then after swiping it hides the notifications, and shows the pattern lock saying "Draw unlock pattern". So the unlocking requires two steps (swiping and then drawing).

Andriod 4 directly shows notifications and the pattern lock below them. The screen is smaller than on the Android 10 phone, but it still all fits on the screen. How can this be achieved on Android 10, without the unnecessary first swiping step?

This is not about Android 3 like [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12106/only-use-pattern-lock-instead-of-swipe-screen-and-pattern-lock) nor Android 6 like [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/142129/swipe-required-before-pattern-unlock-on-marshmallow-6).
This is not about changing the timer for the swipe like [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/avoid-both-screen-lock-and-pattern-lock), but about removing the swipe completely.

Comment: claim it to google but we have to live with